# How to use this JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I have face one issue implementing Javascript . Here is the Link

http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/WzA4y/

This is working And I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and I have small files One is html, and another is CSS, I use the Javscript like below code but this is not working as like in jsFiddle above link .

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/jscript" language="javascript">
    var body = $('body'),
    main = $('.main'),
    open_modal = $('.open-modal'),
    close_modal = $('.close-modal'),
    modal_container = $('.modal-container'),
    toggleModal = function() {
        body.toggleClass('body-locked');
        modal_container.toggleClass('dp-block');
    };

    open_modal.on('click', toggleModal);
    close_modal.on('click', toggleModal);

 </script>


</head>

<body>

<button class="open-modal">Button!</button>


<div class="modal-container dp-none">
    <div class="modal">
        <button class="close-modal">Close!</button>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how is this not working? From what I see it works as intended

Comment: what about using docready? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your jquery code in

```
$(function(){
      /* your code here */
});
```

Something like this: (*I made some small changes in your code to make my answer somewhat big*)

```
$(function () {
    var body = $('body'),
        main = $('.main'),
        modals = $('.open-modal, .close-modal'),
        modal_container = $('.modal-container'),
        toggleModal = function () {
            body.toggleClass('body-locked');
            modal_container.toggleClass('dp-block');
        };

    modals.on('click', toggleModal);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , I'm new in JavaSript, One Question, Can you tell me what is the exact difference between Javascript and JQuery ? I can understand and write JavaScript but JQuery is too clumsy to understand...Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DEBAL Well explaining that, is prohibited :D. anyway you can understand what is the difference from this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2490590/1577396).

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your javascript/jquery code into the $(document).ready(function(){}); because otherwise you are trying to access DOM elements before they have loaded.

If you notice in the jsFiddle link you provided, you are using jQuery 1.7.2 and loading the code 'onload' so jsFiddle was doing this for you.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var body = $('body'),
    main = $('.main'),
    open_modal = $('.open-modal'),
    close_modal = $('.close-modal'),
    modal_container = $('.modal-container'),
    toggleModal = function() {
        body.toggleClass('body-locked');
        modal_container.toggleClass('dp-block');
    };

    open_modal.on('click', toggleModal);
    close_modal.on('click', toggleModal);
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, by mistake from my side +1 for the answer, dont knw about the other downvote cheers :)

Comment: script type is `text/javascript` may be the downvote is because of that.. if so, then it is ew... Hey and also, `language` attribute is deprecated. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

Comment: @Mr_Green Oh I never even noticed that, I just copied the OP's code and wrapped it with `$(document).ready(...);`

Comment: @Mr_Green Totally agree, click `-1` and it should have a quick comment box like when you edit a question.